# Is there a way to search for functions among a large folder of libraries (.a and .so files) in UBUNTU?

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu

I have a project in eclipse, using a library and I can import its include files (include directories) to my project without any problem. But I don't know which libraries to include (I know a library path with zillions of libraries) to use some specific functions.

In Ubuntu, is there a tool to search for functions through a list of libraries? There is a tool called "nm", which lists all exported libraries, structures variables etc. of a PARTICULAR library, if there is no "search for function" tool, I will need to write a program that uses "nm" to search and find functions.

Comment: `grep` is a good first step.

Answer (score 0):

Adding in project's proprieties link of your libraries and the headers, you can use the autocompletion, where is the problem?

Supposing you are using Foo library, you have to link it:

```
C/C++Build->Settings->C++ Linker->Libraries
```

Put Foo (-lFoo) in the list.

```
C/C++Build->Settings->C++ Compiler->Includes
```

Put *.h Foo path.

So in your program.. main.cpp

```
#include <Foo/A.h>

int main() {
   A a;
   a. 
}
```

When you click "dot" you see all A method available. Supposing that A has print method

```
int main() {
   A a;
   a.print(); 
}
```

You can go to the definition of method print() by: Ctrl+RightClick

Comment: Actually, my question was exactly about the condition I do not know the name of lib Foo. I know in which .h file my function is, so I press Ctrl + space, I see the signature of my function exists (Header files work). However, the IMPLEMENTATIONS of those functions, resides in a library named libSomething.a or libSomething.so and it does not need to have a name similar to the h files (there may be thousands of h files, and the implementations can be in a single library file). Suppose that I do not have sufficient documentation.